# OutOfMemory while using AsyncTask and a large image

Tags: android, image, android-asynctask, out-of-memory

The class below parses an rss feed and draws images/text on the screen using AsyncTask. I was using a nasa rss feed. Last night I switched to the same feed but with a larger image. Now when I try to press the refresh button it runs out of memory. How can I handle this? I know it's just because the image is so large (roughly 6mb, compared to 36kb of the other image) and I've read that it being static doesn't help either. I don't see any way around it being static though as I need to retrieve final_image as a separate instance of the class for when you set the wallpaper as the image. So everything below works with a smaller image. With a large image, it works once but if you try to push the refresh button (which just runs RssParseSync.execute()) it fails to refresh and I get the error below. I want the larger image because the small image looked really bad when setting it as the wallpaper.

```
public class RssParseSync extends AsyncTask<String,String,Bitmap>{  

        private Activity parent;
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        private static Bitmap final_image; //must be static because a new instance is required to access getFinalImage();


        public RssParseSync(Activity parent){this.parent =parent;}//constructor to pass parent activity, need this to call findViewById

                private XmlPullParser makeParser(){

                }

                @Override
                protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... info){

                    URL iotd;
                    int count=info.length;
                    String title="",link="",description="",date="";

                    System.out.println("Number of params is "+count);

                    try{

                        iotd = new URL("http://www.nasa.gov/rss/lg_image_of_the_day.rss");//set URl
                        BufferedReader in;//new BufferedReader
                        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iotd.openStream()));//get rss

                        XmlPullParserFactory factory;
                        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();//new factory


                        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                        XmlPullParser xpp;
                        xpp = factory.newPullParser();
                        xpp.setInput(in);

                        //rss is now parsed, free to use XmlPullParser functions to move around and evaulate the rss

                        int eventType;
                        eventType = xpp.getEventType();//returns an int which mean different things (START_DOCUMENT,START_TAG,etc)


                    while(eventType!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){//while the document has words

                     switch(eventType){

                        case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT://beginning of xml
                            break;
                        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG://case : at beginning of new tag
                            String tagName=xpp.getName();
                            System.out.println(tagName+" "+xpp.getDepth());

                            if(tagName.equals("title")&& xpp.getDepth()==4){//depth is specific to this certain rss feed, there are multiple tags with the same names
                                info[0]=xpp.nextText();
                                title=info[0];

                            }

                            if(tagName.equals("description")&& xpp.getDepth()==4){//depth is specific to this certain rss feed, there are multiple tags with the same names
                                info[1]=xpp.nextText();
                                description=info[1];    
                                StringBuilder tabbed=new StringBuilder(description);
                                tabbed.insert(0, "\t");
                                description=tabbed.toString();
                                //info[1]=description;
                            }

                            if(tagName.equals("pubDate")){//no depth needed, only one tag is named pubDate
                                info[2]=xpp.nextText();
                                date=info[2];                           
                            }

                            if(tagName.equals("enclosure")&&xpp.getDepth()==4){//this is where our image url is. this url is an attribute of the "enclosure" tag
                                //System.out.println("Enclosure has "+xpp.getAttributeCount());
                                for(int i=0; i<=xpp.getAttributeCount()-1; i++){
                                    System.out.println("in for");
                                    if(xpp.getAttributeName(i).equals("url")){
                                        link=xpp.getAttributeValue(i);
                                        info[3]=link;
                                        //System.out.println(link);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        }
                        eventType=xpp.next();
                    }//switch

                        publishProgress(title,description,date,link);

                        in.close();//close BufferedReader
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }catch(XmlPullParserException e1){
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }catch(IOException e2){
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }         
                    Bitmap image=getBitmapFromURL(info[3]);

                    return image;
                }
                @Override
                protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress){
                    try {
                        System.out.println("onProgressUpdate");
                        resetDisplay(progress[0],progress[1],progress[2],progress[3]);//feeding parsed rss values, title, description, date, and link
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {//both exceptions are thrown by resetDisplay
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image){//error when doing this in resetDisplay.... onPostExecute is invoked by the ui thread so this may be why it works here and not in resetDisplay
                    ImageView imageView=(ImageView) parent.findViewById(R.id.imageDisplay);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
                    final_image=image;
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }

                protected void onPreExecute(){
                     dialog=ProgressDialog.show(parent, "Loading", "Loading the image of the day");
                }

                private void resetDisplay(String title, String description,String date, String link) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{

                    TextView titleView=(TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.imageTitle);
                    titleView.setText(title);

                    TextView dateView=(TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.imageDate);
                    dateView.setText(date);

                    TextView descriptionView=(TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.imageDescription);
                    descriptionView.setText(description);

                }

                public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String url) {
                    try {
                    Bitmap bitmap=null; 
                    InputStream input = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);//Decode an input stream into a bitmap. If the input stream is null, or cannot be used to decode a bitmap, the function returns null.
                    input.close();
                    return bitmap;
                    } catch (IOException ioe) { return null; }

                }

                public Bitmap getFinalImage(){
                    return final_image;
                };


    }//class
```

Refresh method

```
public void onRefresh(){
    System.out.println("in onRefresh");
    new RssParseSync(getActivity()).execute(title,description,date,link);
}
```

Logcat log

```
07-20 17:44:18.470: I/System.out(7581): onProgressUpdate
07-20 17:44:18.770: D/dalvikvm(7581): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 190K, 3% free 26538K/27299K, paused 46ms
07-20 17:44:18.770: I/dalvikvm-heap(7581): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 24107536-byte allocation
07-20 17:44:18.790: D/dalvikvm(7581): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 18K, 3% free 26519K/27299K, paused 23ms
07-20 17:44:18.790: E/dalvikvm-heap(7581): Out of memory on a 24107536-byte allocation.
07-20 17:44:18.790: I/dalvikvm(7581): "AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=13 RUNNABLE
07-20 17:44:18.790: I/dalvikvm(7581):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40d6cac8 self=0x2412840
07-20 17:44:18.790: I/dalvikvm(7581):   | sysTid=7646 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=32889544
07-20 17:44:18.790: I/dalvikvm(7581):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=7 stm=0 core=1
07-20 17:44:18.790: I/dalvikvm(7581):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
07-20 17:44:18.800: I/dalvikvm(7581):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:719)
07-20 17:44:18.800: I/dalvikvm(7581):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:791)
07-20 17:44:18.800: I/dalvikvm(7581):   at com.wajumbie.nasadailyimage.RssParseSync.getBitmapFromURL(RssParseSync.java:162)
07-20 17:44:18.800: I/dalvikvm(7581):   at com.wajumbie.nasadailyimage.RssParseSync.doInBackground(RssParseSync.java:116)
07-20 17:44:18.800: I/dalvikvm(7581):   at com.wajumbie.nasadailyimage.RssParseSync.doInBackground(RssParseSync.java:1)
07-20 17:44:18.800: I/dalvikvm(7581):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
07-20 17:44:18.800: I/dalvikvm(7581):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-20 17:44:18.800: I/dalvikvm(7581):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-20 17:44:18.800: I/dalvikvm(7581):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
07-20 17:44:18.800: I/dalvikvm(7581):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-20 17:44:18.800: I/dalvikvm(7581):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-20 17:44:18.800: I/dalvikvm(7581):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
07-20 17:44:18.800: E/dalvikvm(7581): Out of memory: Heap Size=34019KB, Allocated=26519KB, Limit=49152KB
07-20 17:44:18.800: E/dalvikvm(7581): Extra info: Footprint=27299KB, Allowed Footprint=34019KB, Trimmed=1212KB
07-20 17:44:18.800: D/skia(7581): --- decoder->decode returned false
07-20 17:44:18.800: W/dalvikvm(7581): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aa3a08)
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=34019KB, Allocated=26519KB)
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:719)
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:791)
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at com.wajumbie.nasadailyimage.RssParseSync.getBitmapFromURL(RssParseSync.java:162)
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at com.wajumbie.nasadailyimage.RssParseSync.doInBackground(RssParseSync.java:116)
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at com.wajumbie.nasadailyimage.RssParseSync.doInBackground(RssParseSync.java:1)
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-20 17:44:18.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7581):     ... 5 more
07-20 17:44:19.061: D/OpenGLRenderer(7581): Flushing caches (mode 0)
07-20 17:44:19.061: D/memalloc(7581): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x52738000 size:2088960
07-20 17:44:19.061: D/memalloc(7581): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x52f7c000 size:2088960
07-20 17:44:19.061: D/memalloc(7581): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x53477000 size:2088960
07-20 17:44:19.081: D/OpenGLRenderer(7581): Flushing caches (mode 0)
07-20 17:44:19.111: D/memalloc(7581): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x52bea000 size:524288
07-20 17:44:19.121: D/memalloc(7581): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5367d000 size:524288
07-20 17:44:19.121: D/memalloc(7581): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x53326000 size:524288
07-20 17:44:19.141: D/OpenGLRenderer(7581): Flushing caches (mode 2)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581): Activity com.wajumbie.nasadailyimage.NasaAppActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40d92b30 that was originally added here
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.wajumbie.nasadailyimage.NasaAppActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40d92b30 that was originally added here
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:380)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:372)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:320)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:152)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:557)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:301)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:94)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at com.wajumbie.nasadailyimage.RssParseSync.onPreExecute(RssParseSync.java:142)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at com.wajumbie.nasadailyimage.NasaDailyImage.onRefresh(NasaDailyImage.java:57)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at com.wajumbie.nasadailyimage.NasaAppActivity$1.run(NasaAppActivity.java:48)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at com.wajumbie.nasadailyimage.NasaAppActivity.onRefreshClicked(NasaAppActivity.java:51)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3066)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3538)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14330)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:607)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5008)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-20 17:44:19.181: E/WindowManager(7581):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to resize the image if it is very large.

Do as follows:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(imageUrl).openStream(),null,options);
//use your required height and width in place of 80 (size of imageview maybe)
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,80, 80); 
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(imageUrl).openStream(),null,options);


public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: I want the large image though so that when you set as wallpaper its crisp.

Comment: Then you can resize it according to the size of the wallpaper, it would still look crisp. You can get the size of the screen using the getWindowManager() function of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I just had to use the bitmap.recycle() method in onPreExecute. I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but this works.

```
protected void onPreExecute(){
    if(final_image!=null){

      final_image.recycle();

    }

     dialog=ProgressDialog.show(parent, "Loading", "Loading the image of the day");
                }
```