# Loading images from url into viewpager - outofmemory

Tags: android, image, out-of-memory

Each view of the viewpager had one image view with a Bitmap taken from url.

If I load small images - 100 X 80 px - I never get outofmemory, even if I load 10000 .
If I load bigger images 800 X 60 px - I get outofmemory after 28 -30 images.

I see view pager recycles the images that are in a views , which have been swiped already. (when I swipe back quickly I see the images being loaded again .)

What I cannot figure out - why 10000 small images do not crash the app, but only 30 bigger images do it?

Please have a look at the code below:

```
<PRE>

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {
    final String appurl = "http://drafts.bestsiteeditor.com/cgi-bin/bookcalendar/promoters.pl";
    final String imgurl = "http://drafts.bestsiteeditor.com/promoters/";
    ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
    ViewPager mPager;
    GetServerData mt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);cal.set  (Calendar.SECOND, 0);cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        int monday = (int) (cal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000);
        if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 2) {} else {for (int d = 1; d <= 7; d++) {monday = monday - 86400;cal.setTimeInMillis((long) monday * 1000);if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 2) {break;}}}

        makeWeek(monday);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        return ActionBar.HandleMenu(this, item.getItemId());

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // if (v == show_calendar) {
        // Intent openMenu;
        // openMenu = new Intent(this, WeekCalendar.class);
        // startActivity(openMenu);

        // }

    }

    public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        ArrayList<Event> events;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        Context c;

        public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Event> events) {
            this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            this.events = events;
            this.c = context;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return events.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
            // ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View)object);
            System.out.println("DESTROY destroying view at position "
                    + position);
            View view = (View) object;

            ((ViewPager) container).removeView(view);
            view = null;

        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            View itemView;
            itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_frag, container, false);
            Event e = events.get(position);

            TextView topTextItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFragFirst);
            TextView bottomTextItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            e.setImageView(iv);
            //if (position == 0) {
                ShowImage shim = new ShowImage(imgurl + "th" + e.getId()+ "1.jpg", iv,c);
                shim.execute();
            //}

            Button btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            final String showtoast = String.valueOf(events.size());
            btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Event expired before:" + showtoast,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });


            topTextItem.setText(e.getDsc());
            bottomTextItem.setText(String.valueOf(position) + e.getTitle());

            ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

            return itemView;
        }

    }



    public class Event {
        String id;
        String title;
        String description;
        ImageView iv;

        public Event(String id, String ttl, String dsc) {
            this.id = id;
            this.title = ttl;
            this.description = dsc;
        }

        public void setImageView(ImageView niv) {
            this.iv = niv;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public String getDsc() {
            return description;
        }

        public ImageView getIV() {
            return iv;
        }
    }

    public class Pair {
        public String isonline;
        public ArrayList<Event> events;

    }

    private class GetServerData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Pair> {

        Context context;
        String targetUrl;
        String imgUrl;

        public GetServerData(Context context, String url, String imgurl) {
            this.context = context;
            this.targetUrl = url;
            this.imgUrl = imgurl;

        }

        @Override
        protected Pair doInBackground(Void... params) {


            ArrayList<Event> eventsar = new ArrayList<Event>();

            String isonline = "no";
            Event newevent = null;

            Document doc;
            try {

                doc = Jsoup.connect(targetUrl).get();
                isonline = doc.select("div#isonline").text();

                Elements promoters = doc.select("div.promoters");
                Elements events = doc.select("div.events");
                Elements eventsfull = doc.select("div.eventsfull");

                if (eventsfull.size() > 0) {
                    for (Element event : eventsfull) {
                        String temp = event.text().toString();
                        String title = event.select("div.title").text();
                        String event_id = event.select("div.event_id").text();

                        String promoter_id = event.select("div.promoter_id")
                                .text();

                        String promoter_name = event.select("div.promoter_name").text();
                        String promoter_email = event.select("div.promoter_email").text();
                        String promoter_phone = event.select("div.promoter_phone").text();
                        String promoter_dsc = event.select("div.promoter_dsc").text();
                        Integer imgs = Integer.parseInt(event.select("div.event_images").text());

                        String[] eventSplit = temp.split("\\|");

                        newevent = new Event(event_id, title, promoter_dsc);
                        eventsar.add(newevent);

                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Pair p = new Pair();
            p.isonline = isonline;
            p.events = eventsar;

            return p;

        }

        @Override
        // protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Integer> rows) {
        protected void onPostExecute(Pair p) {
            String isonline = p.isonline;
            events = p.events;

            if (isOnline()) {

                if (isonline.equals("yes")) {

                    Calendar clt = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                    Long nowt = clt.getTimeInMillis();

    CustomPagerAdapter customPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(context, events);mPager.setAdapter(customPagerAdapter);

                    // mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "No Internet Connection with this page.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Internet Connection at all.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }

    public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void makeWeek(Integer start_day) {
        try {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int myRandom = rand.nextInt() % 3;
            mt = new GetServerData(MainActivity.this, appurl+ "?action=getevents&weekmonday=" + start_day + "&rand="+ myRandom, imgurl);
            mt.execute();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    private class ShowImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView imgV;
        String imgsrc;
        Bitmap d;
        Context c;



        public ShowImage(String src, final ImageView v,Context cntx) {
            this.imgV = v;
            this.imgsrc = src;
            this.c=cntx;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //InputStream is = null;
            //try {
                // is = (InputStream) new URL(imgsrc).getContent();

                //URL url = new URL(imgsrc);
                //d = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection()
                        //.getInputStream());

            //} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            //} catch (IOException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            //}

            InputStream in = null;

               try{
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(imgsrc));
                    in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
               try {


                    d = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                } finally {
                    if (in != null) { try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } }
                }




            return d;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap dr) {

            imgV.setImageBitmap(dr);

            if (dr != null) {

                dr=null;

            } 




        }

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am definitely *not* an expert in `ViewPager`'s inner mechanisms, but let's assume for a moment that it really properly recycles `Bitmap` objects attached to the `ImageView` instances you create for each fragment. My best guess, in this case, would be that, when you load smaller images the recycling mechanism does its magic before you hit the memory cap, so you never experience an OOME; however, when you load bigger images, the recycling mechanism is not able to prevent the OOME, because the chunks of memory you request are consuming available space quite a lot quicker.

This unsatisfactory guess aside, loading images in Android is a dreadful task, that I would try to delegate to libraries or some ready-made code solution rather than endure it myself. If you want to learn more about the task, there is a whole section in the official Training documentation dedicated to it, entitled [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html), which I would read, and read again from time to time, just to avoid forgetting how complex can become this stuff. The code attached to the documentation is even more involved, so it's a good read too.

Then, there are a couple of libraries apt to some use cases for image loading: you can check Picasso, Volley, and Android Universal Image Loader. I believe they all take care of downloading images, setting `Bitmap`s to `ImageView`s, proper resizing and recycling, and especially caching, in memory and on disk. I have personally used Picasso only, and found it satisfying enough for the task I had at hand.

Comment: Picasso behaves great - thank you, but still OOM shows, BUT the app does not crash, and what is strange - the OOM shows at exactly the same view number 28 - and then after 3 views start to show images again, and then shows several view normally with images, and then again 3 without the images , and this way forever :) maybe I should reduce those images indeed.

Comment: @BestSiteEditor I think Picasso's API features a method which you pass width and height of the desired resulting image to, and it should properly resize the bitmap to match those parameters.

Comment: You are absolutely right Giulio , I am currently exploring options provided by Picasso, they could have named it Mozart - goes better with that functionality, Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should shrink your images, otherwise their processing requires to much memory causing OOM. For bigger images its more difficult to find long free address space, its easier for smaller images, you can find sample solution in this SO:

[OutOfMemory while using AsyncTask and a large image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588699/outofmemory-while-using-asynctask-and-a-large-image?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I think that in `destroyItem` you are detaching the `ImageView` but the `Event` objet still holds a reference to it, so it can not be garbage collected. Do you really need this reference ? (you create a new `ImageView` each time).

By the way it's probably a good idea to shrink the images and to use a cache. Quite a few libraries can do that for you.

Comment: However, AFAIK, it's the `Bitmap` object associated to the `ImageView` that you need to recycle, not the `ImageView` itself. So, keeping `ImageView` references around would not be a problem in this case, _if_ the `Bitmap` objects associated to them gets properly recycled, e.g. by some `ViewPager` inner mechanism.

Comment: I did try to set the bitmap in the object, and later to recycle it on some view change but could not do it unfortunately. I watch the youtube app for example - thousands of images ,and big one , and never OOM ?!?!

Comment: Giulio Piancastelli : True, but as the `ImageView` was not reused anyway the simplest solution was to get rid of it completely. The `ViewPager` has no inner recycling mechanism (unlike `Listview` and other `AdapterView`), this is handled by the adapter

Comment: So the only reasonable cause for OOME to appear only when bigger images are loaded is the one provided by @marcin_j I guess?

Comment: BestSiteEditor : replacing the `ImageView` with a `Bitmap` doesn't help. As pointed by Giulio Piancastelli it's in fact the bitmap witch use a lot of memory. I think you have 2 solutions :
1) no cache : store nothing in the object an reload every time
2) implement proper caching : this is quite a bit of work (e.g. handle cache eviction). This is why it usually delegated to a library.

Comment: Giulio Piancastelli: shrinking the image is a good advice, wether you cache it or not

Comment: It is indeed! It just doesn't directly addresses the OP's question about the inconsistent behavior he was experiencing - I mean, it doesn't explain the cause, even if it probably is apt to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should refere to android Trainging [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) 
there they are telling you how to load images and without out of memory exception .

Hope taht helps